# How can I free the port 1701 which is locked by System?

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, process, l2tp

Environment: Window form application, C#, Windows 10.

Hi, I wrote a window form application. This application will try to connect to L2TP VPN server by rasdial.exe via Process class.

The problem is sometimes the VPN server doesn't stable and it will let the connection stop and hang. Once the connection hangs, the application can not reconnect to the VPN server. Even manually.
I found one process keep listening to the ports 500, 4500. svchost.exe (netsvcs -p)

So I try to kill the process by Process.GetProcessById(..).Kill(); Now I found the port 1701 is listened by System. as the screenshot below. I can not kill this process.

I have tried to Disable and Enable the Ethernet, but not working. Only worked if I restart the computer.

My question is if there is a way to let the System free this port without restarting the system?

[The screenshot of resource monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMdIk.png)

------ Update 2021-09-12 --------------------------------------------------

I go to the service from the process list. I found ports 500, 4500 are listened to by the IKEEXT service. and port 1701 is listened by System, no service related.

If I don't kill the processes that locked the ports. Any solution to let the VPN can dial and connect?

Comment: If you are attempting to kill svchost.exe then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: That is the Microsoft store. On Details tab in Task Manager right click the column headers and add *Command Line*. Select `svchost.exe -k netsvcs -p` and right click and choose *Go To Service*.

Comment: @Ramhound I try to not kill the process and the ports 500, 4500 are listened to by the IKEEXT service.  The VPN status show "Disconnecting". I try to restart the service but nothing change. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: @user1292580, I have try to restart the Microsoft store service but not working. The ports are listened to by IKEEXT.